# A question about groups and subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am working from [these](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/courses/345/reviews/revs2.pdf) lecture notes. 
For this example,

> **Example.**  List the elements of the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ generated by $(6,10)$.
>
> $$
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \langle (6,10) \rangle &=& \left\{ (0,0), (6,10), (4,5),(2,0),(0,10), (6,5),\right.\\
> & &\left.(4,0),(2,10),(0,5),(6,0),(4,10),(2,5)\right\}.
> \end{eqnarray*}$$

do I just write down several multiples of 6 and 15 and look at what those multiples are $\mod 8$ or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Also, for this example,

> **Example.** Explain why no element of $\mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ can generate the group.
>
> In fact, the largest order of an element of $\mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is $(8,10)=40$.  The element $(1,1)$ has order $40$.  And if $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, then $40\cdot (x,y)=(40x,40y)=(0,0)$.  So the order of $(x,y)$ is no greater than $40$.

why does the fact that the largest possible order is $40$, tell us that no element can generate the group $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind copying the relevant questions in the pdf to your question? If you aren't sure of the necessary latex commands, someone can edit it for you.

Comment: And *please*: do NOT number the examples in your question if they are not numbered in the PDF document! Better, mention the example as "third example in page 3" or something like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generated by g means the set (which turns out to be a cyclic subgroup) {g, g+g, g+g+g, ...} until you get back to where you started.

so {(6,10), (12, 20), (18, 30), (24, 40), ...} and written reduced that's {(6,10), (4, 5), (2, 0), (0, 10), ...}.

A slightly easier way to do this is write out the group by 6 in Z_8 then by 10 in Z_15 and piece them together:

- 6, 4, 2, 0
- 10, 5, 0

since they have different periods it'll be like this:

```
 6  4  2  0  6  4  2  0  6  4  2  0
10  5  0 10  5  0 10  5  0 10  5  0
```

which is exactly what's written there.

---

The group Z_8 x Z_10 has 80 elements (there are 80 pairs (x,y) where x is < 8 and y < 10). An element can only generate the whole group if it has the same order as the whole group.

Answer (score 2):

In example 2, the subgroup is generated by $1$ element. You start by writing $(6, 15)$ and its multiples (mod 8 and 15 of course) until you get $(0, 0)$. That seems efficient enough to me.

In example 10, the group $\mathbb Z_8 \times \mathbb Z_{10}$ has $80$ elements. A group generated by 1 generator will have the same size as the order of the generator. Knowing that all elements have order not greater than $40$ means you cannot generate a group of order greater than $40$ with 1 element.